# problems extracting string data from excel columns into hashmap

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to extract some data from excel to Hashmap in Java. For this purpose I am using Apache POI library and version is Java 8. The data is in format as shown below:

```
Excel_Data.xlsx: 

    Title    | Label A  | Label B  | Label C 

    Signal 1 | value A1 | value B1 | value C1
    Signal 2 | value A2 | value B2 | value C2
    Signal 3 | value A3 | value B3 | value C3
```

All the text written here is in `String` format and there are no numerical types present in the file

**What I want:**

I want to store data to Hashmap in the form of `key` and `value` pairs, so my output should be:

```
Expected Approach:

Key      ->    Value

Signal 1 -> [value A1, value B1, value C1 ...] 
Signal 2 -> [value A2, value B2, value C2 ...] 
Signal 3 -> [value A3, value B3, value C3 ...]
```

This approach I want to implement because I want to print this data into another excel file following the order of signals

```
Expected_output.xlsx:

Signal 1 | value A1
         | value B1
         | value C1
Signal 2 | value A2
         | value B2
         | value C2
Signal 3 | value A3
         | value B3
         | value C3
```

**What I tried:**

I tried finding this solution online but due to its specificity I did not find any solutions. I also tried to find solutions where keys and values are both extracted as `String` from excel in hashmap, but didn't got much help either.

I came up with an approach where I decided to store `Keys` to `String` and `Values` to `ArrayList` as shown in below code:

```
// this function loads data from excel file stored in filestream variable
public void storeData(){
    //this hashmap will be used to hold values of excel file in key:values format
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    String key = null;
    ArrayList<String> value = null;

    try {
        // get workbook instance of xlsx file
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(open_excel_data);

        //Get first sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // for each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                key = cell.getStringCellValue();

                value.add(cell.getStringCellValue()); // I cannot think of what should be here to store labels in correct format to arraylist

                if(key != null && value != null)
                {
                    map.put(key, value);
                    key = null;
                    value = null;
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**P.S.**

- Its a huge file with lots of Signals and Labels
- It has to be done using Java as this functionality will be part of an already built software tool
- You can even suggest me other easy approaches to fulfill this task if you have anything in mind

Comment: You are setting the array list as null (at first and each time in the loop) and trying to call add() on null. That would cause NPE. Is that the issue you are facing?

Comment: Also, you are not skipping the first row, which seems to be not required in the map you build.

Comment: Also, you are setting key with every cell's value.

Comment: @NaveedS hey I took note about ArrayList. I was setting it to null. But thats not the only issue. Still I need to come up with an algorithm which will try adding data in above mention format `key -> values`. I am trying below given solution in answer below.

Comment: Also, first row values has to be preserved because I also need to print the title and labels along with rest of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {

    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    // for each row, iterate through each columns
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator(); 
    key = null;  
    value = new ArrayList<String>();     

    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

        if(columnIndex == 1) {
            key = cell.getStringCellValue();
        } else {
            value.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

    if(key != null && value != null) {
        map.put(key, value);
        key = null;
        value = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am currently trying out your solution. I think this approach should work, but first I'll give it a quick try.

Comment: Sorry for accepting this answer little late. I was away from computer all weekend. I only had to change `columnIndex == 1` to `columnIndex == 0` as column index starts with 0. Rest of the code works well for me as it helps me to build `key` and `values` structure as shown in Expected Output section of above's question

Answer (score 2):

```
// this function loads data from excel file stored in filestream variable
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> storeData(String fileName) {
        // this hashmap will be used to hold values of excel file in key:values
        // format
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        String key = null;
        ArrayList<String> value = null;
        int keyIndex = 0;
        try {
            // get workbook instance of xlsx file
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                key = null;
                value = new ArrayList<String>();
                // for each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                // To skip first row
                if (row.getRowNum() == 0){
                    continue;
                }

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == keyIndex){
                        key = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    } else {
                        value.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                }

                if (key != null && value != null && value.size()>0) {
                    map.put(key, value);
                    key = null;
                    value = null;
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to skip first row. I will use this solution if needed. As of now I have to keep first row as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, you never create an empty ArrayList for 'value'. For each row you need to create an empty ArrayList, otherwise you can't add values. Furthermore, if you iterate over the rows and then iterate over the cells, only the first cell of each row contains the key. This way key and value is always the same. You must not overwrite the key after it's set in the first cell entry.

Comment: okay. thanks for pointing out about ArrayList. I will give it one more try right now.